# Regex to extract info on the (.*)

Tags: python, regex

**EDIT:**

Real example:

```
@george Hi, I want to buy your car listed for 2500 in Seattle.
```

I want to be able to extract george,car,2500,Seattle.
Using findall i reached this stage

```
re.findall("(.*)Hi, I want to buy your (.*) listed for (.*) in (.*)",buy)
```

which returns a tuple with all the findings.

```
output: ('@george ', 'car', '2500', 'Seattle.')
```

I tried using .split(",")
but it returns a 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: There is not enough context to be sure what you would like to do. But I guess `re.findall()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Try: `re.findall(r"(?<=\n)(\S+) (\S+?)(?=\n)-", curr)`

Comment: i gues you would use match and then use an array of matches

Comment: *i want this for a very large regex with multiple `(.*)`* - Don't. Read the content line by line, once you find a matching line save it in a list variable (or write to DB, etc.). BUT what is the criterion?

Comment: Please explain the real life problem you have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my post. If you want to take a look.

Comment: Why `re.findall` ? Use `re.search`. See https://ideone.com/RrnBtb. You need no `split` here, you already got the items in a tuple actually. It will be a list of tuples if you use `re.findall`

Comment: Why isn't the tuple what you want? What would you gain by a `split`?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/RrnBtb

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew someone reccommended here to use findall. Anyway what you did was exactly what i wanted. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the first match with `re.search`, and you may access all groups using `match.groups()`:

```
import re
buy = r'@george Hi, I want to buy your car listed for 2500 in Seattle.'
m = re.search(r"(.*)Hi, I want to buy your (.*) listed for (.*) in (.*)",buy)
for g in m.groups():
    print(g)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RrnBtb). Output:

```
@george 
car
2500
Seattle.
```